# ajax jquery won't pass the string to the task function?

Tags: jquery, ajax, joomla, components

I'm trying to make a joomla component and I would like to use it the given possibilities from ajax jquery. The task would be to make threw ajax querys from database and to output the result.

to send the data I'm using the following javascript

```
$(".searchBtn").click(function(){

       $('.default_order').hide();

    //show the loading bar

    showLoader();

    $('#sub_cont').fadeIn(1500);



    $("#content #sub_cont").load("?option=com_glossary&task=displayvalues&format=raw?val="+ $("#search").val(), hideLoader());



});
```

what actually should send a variable in string form to my controller, but when I'm checking if the variable existing or not doesn't output anything

```
     public function getvalues(){

         $rec = $this->checkValues(JRequest::getVar('val'));
         echo $rec;
```

}

every comment would help 
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume it's this:

```
...&format=raw?val=" + ...
```

Shouldn't this be

```
...&format=raw&val=" + ...
```

? I would also suggest to [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) the contents of `#search` otherwise you could get in trouble with URL encoding:

```
..." + $("#search").serialize(), ...
```